# Attempting to transpose a matrix using python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, transpose

I know I am missing some pieces to produce this matrix but I cannot seem to find my mistakes from the start.

I have three tasks.

1) Show what the empty matrix will look like.
 2) Show the original matrix(4x3). 
 3) Then transpose the matrix to a 3x4.

```
import sys
from scanner import *

def createMatrix(size):
    if size == 0: return []
    else:
        return [0] + createMatrix(size -1)

def printGrid(gridlist):
    for row in gridlist:
        print (str(row)+"\n")

def nrows(g):
    return len(g)

def ncols(g):
    return len(g[0])

def printMatrix(g):
    for i in range(0,nrows,1):
        for j in range(0,ncols,1):
            print("The original matrix is:",g[i][j])
        print('')
    print('')

def printMatrixTranspose(g):
    for j in range(0,ncols,1):
        for i in range(0,nrows,1):
            print("The transposed matrix is:",g[i][j])
        print('')
    print('')

def readInput(filename,grid):
    s = Scanner(filename)
    r = s.readtoken()
    while r != "":
        r = int(r)
        c = s.readint()
        v = s.readint()
        grid[r][c]=v
        r = s.readtoken()
    s.close()

def main():
    grid = createMatrix(5)
    for i in range(4):
        grid[i] = createMatrix(5)
    readInput(sys.argv[1],grid)
    printMatrixTranspose(g)

main()
```

I keep getting this error, not sure how to fix it.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transpose.py", line 51, in <module>
    main()
  File "transpose.py", line 48, in main
    readInput(sys.argv[1],grid)
  File "transpose.py", line 37, in readInput
    r = int(r)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'method'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are managing a matrix as a list of lists, transposing is quite simplying using your list as an argument into the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function, like so:

```
x = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]

print x
print map(list,zip(*x))
```

We [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) the [`list()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) function across the output of `zip` as zip returns list of tuples, not a list of lists.

The above prints:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
[[1, 4, 7, 10], [2, 5, 8, 11], [3, 6, 9, 12]]
```

edit: That error suggests that the code you've added doesn't match what you are running. Check your file is saved, and verify there are brackets `()` after each call to `readtoken`.

Comment: i have a file already created i have to import in the command line, my main goal is going from a 4x3 to a 3x4.
example:
 'original'
'1 2 3 4'
'5 6 7 8'
'9 10 11 12'

when the program runs it should create:
'1 4 7 10'
'2 5 8 11'
'3 6 9 12'

Comment: also, right now im getting a "type error: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Comment: add the error into your question ,with line numbers and a full traceback.

Comment: '
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "transpose.py", line 51, in <module>
        main()
      File "transpose.py", line 48, in main
        readInput(sys.argv[1],grid)
      File "transpose.py", line 40, in readInput
        grid[r][c]=v
    TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
'

Comment: **add the error into your question ,with line numbers and a full traceback.**